# Add an Icon to input field when invalid value entered

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm working on an form using Materialize CSS, which does very basic validation as the user fills out the form. For example, if a user forgets the `@` symbol in the email field,  a class named `invalid` is added that displays a red line on the bottom of the field. I've been tasked with adding another visual indicator (specifically an alert icon) when the invalid class has been fired.

Initially, I though I could take advantage of the icon suffix feature of Materialize. I've put together a fiddle that I've been working through with no success.

Essentially, I'm setting .material-icons to display none, then I'm trying to show the class if the input hasClass invalid. Here's what I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('input').hasClass('invalid')){
     $('.material-icons').show();
   }
});
```

The CSS:

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";

.input-field.suffix i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: color .2s;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.input-field.suffix i.active {
  color: #26a69a;
}

.input-field.suffix input,
.input-field.suffix textarea {
  margin-right: 3rem;
  width: 92%;
  width: calc(100% - 3rem);
}

.input-field.suffix textarea {
  padding-top: .8rem;
}

.input-field.suffix label {
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field suffix col s6">
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">email</label>
      <i class="material-icons">email</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Maybe I'm looking at this wrong, but believe that I should be able to detect if an element has a class and then do something.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s4356an/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the icon is next to the input box, you can simply use:

```
.material-icons {
  display: none;
}

.invalid ~ .material-icons {
  display: block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pc0m8dq/)**

Comment: Fantastico! The best solutions are often times the most simple. Grazie!